# Magento 2 - Getting error while access the site

Tags: magento2

I'm getting the below error while access the website.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/rugsahos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384 Stack trace: #0 /home/rugsahos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('__construct('_createConfigMerger('Magento\Framewo...', '_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator)) #4 /home/rugsahos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(275): Magento\Framework\Config in /home/rugsahos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 384

Can you please let me know the proper solution for this error?

Comment: Its depends on your last action. Could you please check var/log or var/report  folder on Magento root to get more details ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Note: You can set php version according to your instance.

Comment: while enter the above command in terminal this error is showing sudo: /bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Comment: I guess you are using linux system, if so it seems like you do not have super user permission to access this on SSH. Kindly contact your system administrator.

Comment: yes we are using linux server

Comment: So you'll maybe have only permission to run magento 2 commands only. Kindly contact your system administrator person to install these libraries.